# TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python, join

I'm a total newbie and trying to troubleshoot some code copied from someone's program. Currently:

```
#INITIALIZE OUTPUT FILE AND WRITE HEADER ROW
outfp = open(outfn, "w")
outfp.write('.'.join(fields, '\t') + '\n')  # header
```

produces the following error:

TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given).

Based on what I've seen in some other threads I think "\t".join might be an option but I'm not clear how I'd get this to account for both "\t" and "\n". Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is the expected output of your `join`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are giving `str.join()` two arguments:

```
'.'.join(fields, '\t')
```

`fields` and `'\t'` are two separate arguments. If you wanted to use tabs to join the values in `fields`, you need to use `\t` as the string on which you call the `str.join()` method:

```
'\t'.join(fields)
```

I'm assuming that trying to join with the `'.'` string was a misunderstanding on your part how this works. This produces a string, so you can then append a newline to that:

```
outfp.write('\t'.join(fields) + '\n')  # header
```

However, if you are trying to produce a tab-separated file, you would be much better off using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
 writer = csv.writer(outfn, delimiter='\t')
 writer.writerow(fields)
```

The `csv.writer()` object takes care of conversion to string, proper quoting as needed, writing the delimiter (tabs in the above example) and adding newlines.

Comment: IMO, there is a bit more clean way: `"".join(('\t', fields, '\n'))`

Comment: @serghei: that is not a 'more clean way'. That doesn't produce correct output.